# problem with extjs fields layout

Tags: layout, extjs4

i have the problem with displaying fields on form

```
var test = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: 'test',
        title: '1. zzzz',
        width: 800,
        bodyPadding: 5,


        defaults: {
            anchor: '100%'
        },
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            defaults: {
                anchor: '100%'
            },
            layout: 'column',
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                fieldDefaults: {
                    msgTarget: 'side',
                    labelWidth: 75

                },
                columnWidth: .5,
                flex: 1,
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                defaults: {
                    anchor: '100%',
                    flex: 1
                },
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'numberfield',
                    hideTrigger: true,
                    fieldLabel: 'zzzz',
                    //anchor: '100%',
                    //anchor: '-5',
                    name: 'SRD_NUMBER'
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'zzzz',
                    //anchor: '-5',
                    name: 'SRD_NAME_BR'
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'zzzzz',
                    //anchor: '-5',
                    name: 'SRD_NAME_FL'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'numberfield',
                    hideTrigger: true,
                    fieldLabel: 'zzzz',
                    disabled: true,
                    //anchor: '-5',
                    name: 'SRD_FOP'
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'zzzz',
                    //anchor: '-5',
                    name: 'SRD_NAME_ORDER'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    id: 'dep-img',
                    border: false,
                    height: 50,
                    width: 100,
                    cls: 'x-form-item',
                    html: '<img src="http://dep-image/id/10000001482" width="100" height="50" title="zzz">'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'filefield',
                    name: 'file1',
                    msgTarget: 'side',
                    border: 3,
                    //anchor: '100%',
                    fieldLabel: 'zzzz',
                    buttonText: 'zzzzzz'
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'zzz',
                    //anchor: '-5',
                    name: 'company'
                },
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'zzzz',
                    //anchor: '-5',
                    name: 'company'
                }]
            }
            ]
        } //fieldset
        ]//glob

    });
```

i need to fit fields width to column width.

on this page http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer 2 examples
and in second example they set `defaults {layout: '100%'}` and it looks like it does not work.

**found own salvation**: by adding layout: 'fit' or layout: 'anchor' to fieldset anchor
defaults: {
   layout: 'fit',
   flex: 1
},

thanks to all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found own salvation: by adding layout: 'fit' or layout: 'anchor' to fieldset anchor

```
defaults: {
   layout: 'fit',
   flex: 1
},
```

thanks to all

Comment: Can you expand or provide an example of "layout: 'acnchor' to fieldset anchor"?

Answer (score 4):

You must set **height** property to your **form** and if it still is not displaying  then give height to fieldset too.

Answer (score 1):

I would specify layout:'fit' on the formPanel since you are using a single fieldset.

The rest i dont understand. It looks like you specify column layout but using just one column.

Could you clean up the example and i would be happy to help.

Answer (score -3):

After a quick look... Have you tried putting anchor: '0' on both fields and containers?

Also, you should use fieldDefaults instead of

```
 defaults: {
                anchor: '100%',
                flex: 1
            },
```